# Tidying comments on my question, why were they all declined?

Tags: support, flags, comments

I was flagging comments on one of my older [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890800/setting-up-ontouch-listeners-on-specific-x-y-points-on-screen) as obsolete to tidy it up (I'd received working answers) but when I looked in my flag history all of them had been declined.

[image]

As far as I could see none of the comments added to the question or answers. Also I had deleted my comments as I was flagging, so whats left looks kind of confusing. I'm just wondering why they weren't accepted? Is it because they help clarify the Q/A in some way?

Isn't is encouraged to tidy comments once the question has an accepted, working answer (provided they don't add anything)?

Comment: Yes, it's encouraged, and yes those comments are obsolete. Perhaps the flags took someone aback because it's weird to see someone performing this cleanup on their own a month after the fact, and it may have triggered a "this guy is trying to hide something" knee-jerk response. But I can't see why the flags would have been declined, when we're constantly told that comments are second-class citizens and can be removed for precisely this reason at any time. You did the right thing by raising this here, though I'm concerned how often this may be happening when the victim doesn't then come to meta.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I didn't think that it might look like that, should I re-flag them then?

Comment: I'd wait and see what a mod says here.

Comment: [Related post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/245167)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was the one who processed the flags and I declined them because they didn't appear to be obsolete.

When we review comment flags, we don't see the question or answer at the same time. We are only presented with the comment so we have no context of *obsoleteness*.  During the workflow, if I have a question about whether a comment needs to be removed, we can drill into the question/answer to review further.  I didn't do that with these because I didn't see anything about the comments that needed to be removed.

My suggestion would be if you want to clean up older posts because the comments are all old, etc. then flag the post or a comment using an "Other" flag and say "All comments here are old, outdated and can be removed."  This type of flag will get our attention to look a bit closer at the comments and we will handle the clean up.

After further review from your question, I've corrected my mistake and removed the comments.

Comment: Thanks, will do in the future :), I didn't realise you couldn't see all at once

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are they considered obsolete? Aren't they still relevant to the question?

Comment: @Anonymous They were part of a larger conversation that had partially been removed, so they no longer made sense without the other comments.

Comment: So the obsolete flag is [status:broken-by-design] since without context you can't know if a comment is obsolete.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I wouldn't say broken, obsolete works best with stuff like "Check my updated...", "My database is...", etc

Comment: I just figured the conversation wouldn't help anyone else anymore, since if they had the same problem there was the answer. Thus they were now obsolete. That was my interpretation of the obsolete flag (which was wrong, as I now see :)). However in future I will flag as other

Comment: It seems self-evident that you need to read the post and comment thread to determine whether an "obsolete" comment flag is invalid. Can you expand on the reasons that this was not performed?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Most of the time we can make a judgment on comments without seeing the post which is why I didn't see the need to dig into this further.  Reading the comments, they didn't appear to be obsolete so the flags were declined.

Comment: @bluefeet: But, with respect, is the case under discussion not evidence that this approach is insufficient? I think we can agree that the comments _were_ obsolete.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, I wouldn't say it's insufficient. We can typically tell how to process the flags on first glance.  If it is not immediately obvious, then yes, I'll drill into the post but when I reviewed the comments in question, I didn't see them as obsolete so I declined the flags.

Comment: @bluefeet: Yes I understand that but... well, you were wrong. :/ I'm not accusing you of anything, merely suggesting that the policy/UI/workflow that led to this is flawed. Oh well.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I've since corrected my mistake, so there really isn't anything else to say, right? :D  And we are aware that the UI isn't very [user friendly for mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224532/do-not-prompt-for-confirmation-to-delete-a-comment-in-the-moderator-dashboard) when we are processing comment flags but that's another story.

Comment: @bluefeet: There could be an enhancement idea or a mod policy change in here somewhere to prevent it from happening again, is my point. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I get your point and we have asked for some enhancements but alas that takes 6-8 weeks or months or...

Comment: @bluefeet Yes, it is true that for almost all comment flags *besides obsolete flags* there is no need to see the context to evaluate if the comment should be deleted, but virtually every obsolete flag ever cast will require looking at the context to evaluate.  You shouldn't be declining such flags without looking at the context, as it's essential to evaluating the comment in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: I should point out that even with the context of the edited post, it can sometimes be hard to process "obsolete" comment flags. It usually requires a little technical examination of the edited post to determine that the concerns in the comments have indeed been addressed. If I can't see this clearly, I tend to decline the flags (the only option we have aside from deletion). You don't see the volume of flags like this we get from people trying to eliminate any comments critical of their posts, so you don't want us to blindly accept these.

Comment: But surely if the moderators don't want to spend the time to determine if a flag is valid, they shouldn't be processing the flag. You can't just go around blindly declining flags either - why would anyone want to bother with flagging after that?

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier - ["There are almost always more useful things to do than to stress about comments."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237978/a-guide-to-moderating-comments/237982#237982)

Comment: There is a high volume in the edit review queue, too, but we would be badly misbehaving if we simply went in there and robo-declined them because examination of each would "take too long"

Comment: Also, given the concept that we own our posts to the extent that we can tell people not to edit them, it seems an OP should have final say in the comments as well. It is **my** post, after all, if I say the comments are obsolete then they are.

Comment: @BradLarson so the bigger picture I get from that quote is that basically: don't bother flagging comments, because nobody here expects the moderators to spend any time with them. Which just seems weird that we offer a flag option on comments that the top guys around here are expected to ignore.

Comment: Moderators don't ignore comment flags, @Richard. Mods on SO handle on average 500 comment flags each *day*, 93% of them marked helpful (the flagged comment deleted). That's on top of all the other flags, many of which often require a fair bit of investigation and analysis. As far as I'm concerned, if a comment flag takes more than a few seconds to evaluate, the person evaluating it is doing it wrong - comments are not important enough to require more than that. If such flags continue to be a matter of contention, we'll just remove that bit of information from user profiles and be done with it.

Comment: @Shog9 Cool I think I'm starting to see what you guys mean. So this thread is really about the edge case?

Comment: Correct, @richard. As bluefeet stated in this answer, it was a mistake - mods are human, those happen.

Comment: @Chris That's exactly the wrong mentality.  If I explain in a comment why your answer is incorrect, dangerous, and unhelpful, you don't have the right to get that comment deleted just because it's posted in response to your answer.

Comment: @BradLarson Sure, it can sometimes be hard to determine if a comment is obsolete, and if a mod is unsure, they should err on the side of not deleting the post, I agree.  I just have a problem with a mod refusing to ever look at the context of any comment flagged as obsolete.  Without looking at context they will virtually never have a shot at determining if the comment is obsolete, ever.  If, after looking at the context, it's not immediately obvious that the post is obsolete, I have no problem with the comment being left there.

Comment: @Servy I don't think refusing was ever said.

Comment: @Servy: the issue here isn't mods refusing to do anything. It's a flagging UI that wasn't designed to show very much context. That's something we're actively working on improving - bluefeet is merely being honest with y'all as to the situation *as it exists right now*. As a general rule, making sure you've provided moderators with as much information as possible is *always* going to be the best way to ensure that you get the results you're hoping for.

Comment: @Shog9 Which brings us back to [the obsolete flag inherently being broken](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268494/tidying-comments-on-my-question-why-were-they-all-declined/268497?noredirect=1#comment76893_268497).  The whole idea of an obsolete comment is an entirely appropriate comment that is no longer relevant.  You can pretty much never tell if it is still relevant or not without context, so without taking the time to go to the post and check an informed decision pretty much can't be made.

Comment: Sometimes, the comment conversation itself is sufficient. Sometimes, you have to look a bit further. Sometimes - not often - you think the former is true and it turns out the latter was the case. That's when you make a mistake, @Servy, and that's what I'm talking about when I say we're working on finding a way to expose more context when it counts. But this is hardly limited to the obsolete comment flag; for *any* flag there's gonna be a chance that you're missing something; visible information changes, information overload happens, fatigue...

Comment: @Servy I don't disagree -- I was referencing an earlier incident in which it was stated that an OP has final editorial oversight of their post, to the extent that they're allowed to tell another SO user to not edit their post, and to tell them off if they don't respect that proclamation. My comment intended to follow that line of thinking to the ridiculous conclusion, in which the OP has editorial oversight on the comments as well, being that they're a part of the post.

Answer (score 0):

The obsolete flag is used for something that is no longer relevant. The comments on that post look perfectly relevant and helpful:

> yea - but I would be careful with at (x,y) as it is really hard to hit exact coordinates - better check for a region

Since your question was *Setting up onTouch Listeners on specific x,y points on screen*, that is helpful advice. You probably shouldn't set it for "specific x,y points on screen".

> But i there are some objects on your screen, you should set touch listeners to them. No need to check the coordinates then.

This keeps people from overcomplicating things.

There is no reason to delete these comments. Someone may find future use out of them.

Comment: The "look perfectly relevant" but they were not. Which is why they were flagged. The moderators involved should have taken that into account.