# Privilege: moderate my own content

Tags: feature-request, flags, comments, low-quality-posts, moderation

Moderators seem to take little time dealing with flags, comment flags in particular, and a big part of that is that they are inundated with so many.

At the same time, experienced users get frustrated when their content gets flagged and deleted without notice.  It's especially frustrating when that content could have been saved by editing.

Therefore, I propose that when a flag is cast on a post owned (and last edited) by a user with sufficient reputation (I propose 10k), it appears first to that user.  If the user removes or edits their own post in response, the flag is cleared.  **If the user takes no action, then after 24 hours the flag appears to moderators.  Also, the flags appear sooner in the moderator queue if three or more flags are cast on the same post by unique users.**

This preserves anonymity of the flag submission process, while reducing burden on the diamond moderators and giving users a chance to fix their own content when comments become obsolete, or quality standards concerning link-only answers change in the years after an answer is first posted.

Most minor infractions can be dealt with by the post owner, and we should trust our high rep users enough to let them do so.

I'd like to hear from other members of the community whether they think this idea would work better on certain flag types.  Certainly custom flags have a greater possibility to break anonymity, so perhaps they would be excluded.

It is an intended effect of this proposal that it somewhat reduces the ability of general users to censor the comments of high-reputation users.  Right now the diamond moderators admit that nearly every comment flag leads to immediate deletion, which in effect gives all users, regardless of reputation, a veto over reasonable comments.  I believe that the safeguards that diamond moderators intervene eventually or when multiple flags are cast could provide needed balance.

Comment: And again, downvotes start in less time than it takes to read the idea and realize that safeguards are in place.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you mean by 'content' If it were for obsolete flags on comments, I (and judging by numerous other comments many others) would love to see this for obsolete flags. But for posts I consider this idea to be nonhelpful.

Comment: The issue I take with it is a user could make a 1 character edit and get the flag cleared; that also doesn't take into account a custom flag "Hey, this user is a sock puppet account, or is voting for this other user."  There are a good number of flags that we don't want to be exposed to the person who is flagged, in case they have malicious intent. RE: "Reasonable Comment": I'll re-iterate what I said there: [`TL;DR` is not a reasonable comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290148/technical-comment-removed/290192#comment176904_290192).

Comment: also a downvote can simply mean disagreement and not ignorance. Assuming the worst in people often gets you what you expect. Assuming the best may be harder but it's IMO more rewarding

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "minor infractions"? There are plenty of flags that I wouldn't want a post owner to simply be able to process themselves.  Plus I think 24 hours is far too long before hitting the moderator queue. There are things that should be escalated much faster than that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker custom flags are explicitly excluded...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Do we have a problem with sock puppet accounts with 10k reputation?  I thought they mostly got to a couple hundred only (to be able to upvote).

Comment: @Vogel612 I'm also thinking of standard flags where only two people have been a part of the post, the OP and the commenter. If the commenter leaves a comment that deserves to be deleted and sees a flag on it, what stops them from taking their anger out on the OP?

Comment: @BenVoigt We have people who try to target votes at all levels of the reputation spectrum.

Comment: I have to disagree with your assessment that _the diamond moderators admit that nearly every comment flag leads to immediate deletion_. This does not happen. We evaluate the flags on comments and make a judgment call to delete or dismiss the flag. There are plenty of comments that get flagged that do not get deleted.

Comment: @bluefeet: [The statistic provided by other diamond mods is 95% deletion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280554/103167)

Comment: @BenVoigt Since [90% of everything is crap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law), I think we're doing OK there.

Comment: @BenVoigt We don't just push the delete button, we still evaluate the comment before making a decision, I think you are missing that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: Re: "reasonable comment" If you're saying it could have been phrased better, I agree.  If you're saying the comment was valueless, you're just showing your inability to evaluate technical discussions of C++.  You're effectively admitting you didn't get past the first 5 characters of the comment before deciding its value was zero; I'm saying you should give me a chance to salvage the technical portions from what comes across to you as snarky and unacceptable be rewording.

Comment: @bluefeet Exactly. If I spend more than 3 seconds on a comment flag, that's far too long. We (at any given time) have a few hundred comment flags; and that's on top of 4x more other flags. Got to spend time on what matters. Comments do not matter.  Including this one.

Comment: @bluefeet: George is proving you wrong with every comment he makes.  Perhaps you spend longer than three seconds, but most of the diamond moderators do not.

Comment: @BenVoigt [According to Shog9 we shouldn't spend more than a few seconds evaluating comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268494/tidying-comments-on-my-question-why-were-they-all-declined#comment77751_268497). We do evaluate the comment; we just make that decision quickly, because comments do not matter.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker That's what I was getting at, just poorly. We don't just delete, we evaluate the comment, then delete or dismiss quickly based on the direction we've been given - don't spend too long because comments aren't that important.

Comment: To put numbers to what bluefeet was saying above, [read Jon Ericson's statistics on comment flags](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling/251176#251176). We decline 25% of "not constructive" or "off topic" comment flags, 20% of "rude or offensive" flags, and 28% of "other" comment flags. It's not like we rubber-stamp every flag we see. According to Jon, we decline a greater percentage of comment flags than we do standard post flags.

Comment: @BradLarson: Then maybe the answer is for mods to decline more flags with the reason "Try to work it out yourselves first, there's no need for moderator involvement here (yet)"

Comment: The struggle is real

Answer (score 20):

I like the idea of giving people the opportunity to know they've crossed the line.  The problem is there's too much opportunity for it to turn into [a complaint session on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/171032/16587), and that's in the best of cases.

I think it's a good idea for someone to know their comment was deleted.  I like that idea.  I also like the idea that users should have some sort of history of what their comments were.

I also think that there is a hoarding effect with comments.  "My Comment must stay around because [it's Gold Jerry, Gold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0qm0KUPeD8)". I know loss aversion exists because I witness it on Stack Overflow every day. So I get why it isn't a feature. [I still wish it were, though](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170487/16587).

However, due to the practical realities before us, I have to disagree with implementing your feature request.  Here are a few reasons why:

- Users could game the system to make one character edits to clear the flag. We already see this happen to bump edits; and we've even had users rewrite whole questions to get around the 48 hour bounty barrier; so we know users will do just about anything we let them do.  We even have good tools to track suspicious votes, but that doesn't stop users from trying it.
- It lets a user know when their content has been flagged; and in some cases that's all it takes for them to 'seek revenge' on the OP or whomever they think was involved.  It happens nearly daily with downvoting and comments; I can only imagine what it's like if we throw flags into the mix.

Comments are post-it notes. They aren't meant to stick around. [You can increase the chances they will stay around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170420/16587), but you can't guarantee it.

Comment: Well, comment flags couldn't be dismissed by editing, because comments can't be edited.  Only replaced, which involves deleting the old one anyway.

Comment: @BenVoigt Think of it as me saving you a step by deleting your comment. I didn't realize that, since I can edit my own comments at will.

Comment: Your answer shows you know the difference, and that it doesn't "save me a step".  When you delete the comment for me, it (a) hides it from me and (b) doesn't let me know it is gone.  That makes it unhelpful.

Comment: Also, wrt "seeking revenge", don't you think users can still guess why their comments are disappearing, and don't you think they're more upset by outright deletion than a flag giving them a chance to reword it?  Also remember we're only talking about changing how this works for the top 1% of users, who mostly have learned not to go trying to exact revenge over disagreements.

Comment: @BenVoigt That's quite the assertion you've made there. I assure you, the top 1% users are still users. With their own ego and trolling urges. They have bad days at work / school / home like the other 99%, and they too, can try to exact revenge over competition/disagreements. And often with much more efficiency than other users.

Comment: @SecondRikudo: The "bad day" is exactly why good users might write comments in poor taste, and most of the time, they're capable of self-correction when someone points it out.  The problem is the current process gives no opportunity for that.

Answer (score 14):

If we're only going to talk about high-reputation users, let's discuss the most common case where a high-reputation user's content would be flagged: they're being rude or getting into a fight with other users. Above certain reputation thresholds, we don't see a lot of behavior like sock puppetry (because we catch them before that), plagiarism, etc., but abusive behavior towards others exists at all reputation levels.

We try to handle this in stages. First, if a user left a handful of rude comments, we can delete those quietly in response to flags and stop arguments or retaliation before it starts. I think it's better to not notify someone that their comments were removed in that case, because it lets everyone just move on as if it didn't happen.

However, if these comments or posts are particularly over the line or develop into a pattern of behavior, then we clean them up and start to have a conversation with the user about them. No one else needs to know that this happened, and hopefully they'll turn things around.

I've seen long-running feuds between many high-reputation users where each user or group flags the other group's comments in an attempt to have innocuous ones destroyed. Many people also flag anything that provides constructive criticism of their posts.

If these kinds of flags were exposed to high-reputation users on their own content, I can tell you right now that these feuds would escalate into something worse. I don't think all that many people would look at a flag on their comment or post and say "yes, I was a bit excessive here". Instead, the more common reaction will be "how *dare* someone flag this!" and at best Meta will be filled with complaints about people flagging their content.

If edits could clear these flags, this all becomes much worse, since people will abuse this to hide their rude comments or personal attacks from moderators and be able to carry on with behavior that we would have stepped in about.

All that said, this is not what happened with your comment. The "not constructive" comment flags are getting to be a bit of a problem, because people are throwing those around on everything. Most of the things being flagged aren't urgent or don't need moderator attention. That's why I can get behind the community somehow taking care of these (a review queue or whatever). I'd still want third parties to be judging this, not the flagged users themselves.

Comment: Perhaps self-moderation for "not constructive" and "obsolete" comment types only?

Comment: @BenVoigt Same problem that I mentioned above: revenge if there aren't that many actors involved in the post.